# Не могу подгрузить шрифт iText через Resource

Tags: java, itext

Пишу

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fonts/ArialKZ.ttf").getPath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(baseFont, Font.DEFAULTSIZE, Font.NORMAL);
```

Выдаёт ошибку

```
com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: Table 'name' does not exist in **/fonts/ArialKZ.ttf
```

Comment: А какой-нибудь другой шрифт вашим кодом подключается? Уверены, что правильно определяется имя файла со шрифтом? Пробовали вместо имени файла указать наименование шрифта, например "Times New Roman" или "Verdana"?

Comment: @IgorKudryashov если захардкодить то всё норм, т.е. если написать `"./src/main/resources/fonts/ArialKZ.TTF"` то всё будет нормально, т.е. этот же шрифт подключается, если его попросить иначе, более того он же не выдаёт ошибку о том что не нашёл файл, он его находит, но вот что-то дружить с ним не хочет

Comment: другой шритфт пробовали? Возможно ваш ArialKZ.TTF имеет некорректную структуру.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov с другими шрифтами та же история

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Добавил в pom всё заработало, почему не понял

```
     <build>
            <resources>
                    <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/staticresources</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
            </resources>
    </build>
```

Comment: Вот ещё http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712551/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-itextxmlworker-from-servlet-using-custom-font . Там есть ссылки на решение.